# What are the sources that the soul possesses the knowledge of a language?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, language, soul

@AvrohomYitzchok asked me this question to support the assertions for another question: "[why-dont-newborns-speak-outright](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117973/why-dont-newborns-speak-why-do-we-need-to-learn-a-language).

What are the sources that the knowledge of a language is a quality of the soul (רוח או נשמה) as opposed to the earthy body or the animal spirit (נפש)?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%93_%D7%9C%D7%95 מִן הַשָּׁמַיִם הִשְׁמִיעֲךָ אֶת קֹלוֹ לְיַסְּרֶךָּ וְעַל הָאָרֶץ הֶרְאֲךָ אֶת אִשּׁוֹ הַגְּדוֹלָה וּדְבָרָיו שָׁמַעְתָּ מִתּוֹךְ הָאֵשׁ. The Gra explains that *kolo min ha'shamayim* was for the *ruach*, here there is only pre-verbal *kol*. *isho ha'gedolah al ha'aretz* is for the *nephesh*, here there is *dibbur* (words) as well.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Sorry, I don't get it, can you rephrase it for me, please?

Comment: *Kol* in the context of *matan torah* is trans-verbal / pre-verbal sound. This was received by the *ruach* (higher level of the *neshama*). *Dibbur* is comprised of *devarim*, words. This was received by the *nephesh* (lower level of the *neshama*). According to the Gr"a. Which indicates that language and words are a function of the *nephesh*.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Isn't Nefesh called Behemis, namely possessed by all animals? Anyway, does it come from above or from below, that's the question.

Comment: Chassisim (e.g. Chabad) call the *nephesh* - *behamis*. This is a recent innovation and the first reference to this occurs during the 1700's. At any rate, the *nephesh* is from the lower spheres, hence the communication to the *nephesh* is via *ve'al ha'aretz her'achah es esho ha'gedolah*.

Answer (score 1):

Genesis 2:7: “The L-rd G-d formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a nefesh chayah.” Onkelos translates ruach m’mal’la to mean “one with the power of speech,” denoting a certain knowledge of language.

Comment: So this "רח ממללא" was grown-up - speaking right away, right?

Comment: @AlBerko Yes. According to Genesis, Adam was created as an adult, pre-formed. He had the power of speech that G-d gave when it says: “[G-d] breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a nefesh chayah (ruach m’mal’la-the power of speech) (Onkelos).